How to customize Web3Modal wallet menu?
I want to use WalletConnect in my web-based dapp using Javascript.
So I used Web3Modal to ask me the proper wallet to connect to.
I want it to show this menu:

I used this code to connect the proper wallet via the above menu:
const providerOptions = {
    walletconnect: {
        package: WalletConnectProvider.default,
        options: {
            rpc: {
                97: "https://rpc.ankr.com/bsc_testnet_chapel"
            },
            chainId: 97
        }
    }
};
const web3Modal = new Web3Modal.default({
    cacheProvider: true,
    providerOptions
});
let provider = await web3Modal.connect();
let web3 = new Web3(provider);

But it shows the menu as below:

1- How can I control the wallets displayed here?
2- How can I change this window properties, like background color and etc?
3- Do you know any complete document about WalletConnect specially Web3Modal?
